# How do I continue through HTTP errors in urllib.request library?

Tags: python, web-scraping, exception, google-colaboratory, urllib

I am trying to get text from a number of websites. The urls are stored as strings in a list. I am using the urllib.request library, imported as ur. I am using Google Colab. This is the error I am getting, coming from the line "data = page.read()":

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

```
import urllib.request as ur
httpErrors=0

for i in url_List:
  website = ur.Request(i, data=None, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'})
  page = None
  try:
    page = ur.urlopen(website)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    httpErrors+=1
  else:
    print('No errors found.')
  finally:
    print('I found this many HTTPErrors: ' + str(httpErrors))
  
  data = page.read()
  page.close()
```

Here is my output until the error:

```
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
I found this many HTTPErrors: 1
```

Is there a way for me to ignore the error and skip the URL, so I can keep going through the list of URLs? I am pretty new to web scraping and stackoverflow, so apologies for any dumb code or formatting mistakes.

Comment: Try using `continue` whenever you encounter an error where your except block is. This will allow the script to keep going with the rest of the list and ignore any errors(As long as you handle them correctly).

Comment: @KevinHernandez do you mean to put a `continue` under `httpErrors+=1`?

Comment: That is exactly what i mean @sanminchui!